# What is an ordered-vector tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Recently i came across the C++ Policy based data structures library, which has [policy-based binary search trees](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/tree_based_containers.html). Try as I might, I could not find any description of what an ordered-vector tree is. Can someone give me a description of what it is or a link to a complete description?

EDIT: I am also interested in the complexities of the operations(search, insert, deletion) of this structure.

Answer (score 0):

Ordered vector tree simply is an ordered structure ( the structure is a tree here ) that is implemented by a vector. The following link might help you even though it is for Java

[OrderedVector](http://cs.williams.edu/~morgan/cs136-s08/javadoc/structure5/structure5/OrderedVector.html)

Comment: So does this mean that it has linear search, insert and deletion complexities?

Comment: If you look at the link you will get your answer!

Comment: The complexities are never mentioned.

Comment: Your answer lacks details.  Providing a link is not sufficient; the answer must be able to stand on its own if (when) the link is broken.  Edit your answer to add a summary of what an ordered-vector tree is.